# Is there any way of getting webkit's javascript to handle whitespace properly?

Tags: javascript, webkit, whitespace, xslt

It turns out webkit doesn't appear to behave particularly well with whitespace while processing an XSLT. It seems to treat newline, carriage returns, tabs and spaces equally, even to the point where `substring-after('test string','&#10;')` will return `string`.

Is there any way of getting it to behave properly, or is this a bug in webkit that doesn't have a workaround?

EDIT: Here's some javascript that demonstrates the error:

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var xsltText = "<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform\"version=\"1.0\"><xsl:template match=\"test\"><output><xsl:value-of select=\"string-length(substring-after(., '&#10;'))\"/></output></xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>";
var xslt = parser.parseFromString(xsltText, "text/xml");
var xmlText = "<test>test string</test>";
var xml = parser.parseFromString(xmlText, "text/xml");
var xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xslt);
var processed = xsltProcessor.transformToDocument(xml);
var result = processed.firstChild.textContent;
```

The `result` variable should obviously contain '0'; in Safari 4 and Chrome 8 it returns '6'.

Comment: This is reported as a WebKit bug at https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=53375 and the bug report references this StackOverflow question.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce that problem with Safari 5.0.3.
Test case (XML document loaded in browser window):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test2011012801Xsl.xml"?>
<test>foo bar</test>
```

where the stylesheet is

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Test</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="test">
    <p><xsl:value-of select="string-length(substring-after(., '&#10;'))"/></p>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output in both Firefox (3.6) and Safari on Windows is "0". So at least with that test there is no evidence that a space character in a text node is treated as a newline character.

Comment: I first noticed this in Chrome.. admittedly the version of Safari I'm testing with is only 4.0.2, it's possible 5.0.3 uses a newer version of webkit I guess.

Comment: Can you run the test case with your version of Safari? Does it output a number different from 0? In that case there is a bug in that version of Safari. It would also help others to try to reproduce if you post the Chrome version number you see the problem with.

Comment: @Flynn1179: Also tested on Chrome (10.0.648.6 dev). Output: `<html> <head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> <title>Test</title> </head> <body> <p>0</p> </body> </html>`. Do note that XML documents goes through the XML parsers and it's their responsibility to set the context for the XSLT processor. That might make differences with an EmacScript invocation.

Comment: Curiously enough, I get the same result on Safari 4 when I try this xml document rather than invoking the xslt through javascript's XsltProcessor. I'll write some cut down javascript that reproduces it and add it to the question.

Comment: @Fynn1179: Yes, mostly every reported bug for any browser XSLT processor have for context the EmacScript invocation. But when this is XML/XSLT driven, they are all standard complain.