# XSLT convert new line to <br/>

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I can not get this to work. I have seen all the examples on stack overflow and understand the xslt code. But for some reason it is replaceing my space character and not the new line.

```
<t>Line1 Is here 
Line2 Is another 
Line3 Is some more 
</t>
```

The XSLT template is

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">  
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>  
 <xsl:template match="t">  
  <p>  
    <xsl:apply-templates/>  
  </p>  
 </xsl:template>  

 <xsl:template match="text()" name="insertBreaks">  
   <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>  

   <xsl:choose>  
     <xsl:when test="not(contains($pText, '&#xA;'))">  
       <xsl:copy-of select="$pText"/>  
     </xsl:when>  
     <xsl:otherwise>  
       <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($pText, '&#xA;')"/>  
       <br />  
       <xsl:call-template name="insertBreaks">  
         <xsl:with-param name="pText" select=  
           "substring-after($pText, '&#xA;')"/>  
       </xsl:call-template>  
     </xsl:otherwise>  
   </xsl:choose>  
 </xsl:template>  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the result I get is this

```
Line1 
Is 
here Line2 
Is 
another Line3 
Is 
some 
more
```

See my example here http://www.xsltcake.com/slices/VsPbib

It seems to be replacing space characters and not the new line character.

Comment: **I cannot reproduce the problem**. Just copying and pasting the provided XML document and XSLT transformation, then running the transformation on ths XML document, I get this result: <p>Line1 Is here<br/>Line2 Is another<br/>Line3 Is some more<br/> </p> and the browser displayis it as: <p>Line1 Is here<br/>Line2 Is another<br/>Line3 Is some more<br/>
</p> **I get the same result with all 11 XSLT processors I have installed on my computer**: MSXML 3/4/6, .NET XslCompiledTransform and .NET XslTransform, AltovaXML (XML-SPY), Saxon 6.5.4, Saxon 9.1.07, Saxon 9.1.07 for .NET, AltovaXML for XSLT 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue in webkit, which affects Safari and Chrome. Here's the details:

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=53375

I asked a similar question myself a while ago: [Is there any way of getting webkit's javascript to handle whitespace properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822883/is-there-any-way-of-getting-webkits-javascript-to-handle-whitespace-properly)